# Fast Lookup of Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I currently have a String array that I need to search many times for an exact match. What would be the best data structure to use?

```
Example - String array with elements

cat
dog
squirrel
raccoon
aardvark
```

The java code receives searches for strings and iterates over the array:

1. Query for 'dogg' - returns nothing
2. Query for 'raccoon' - returns raccoon

My current code does the following:

```
for (String element : myList) {
      if (element.equals(searchTerm)) {
            return searchTerm;
      }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this search? I thought about using a Map, but I couldn't think of a good value (the key would be the 'dog'/'cat'/etc....). Should I use the same value for the key and the value? Is there a better data structure to use?

Comment: a trie you should use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: @nachokk Joda, is that you?

Comment: @nachokk http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a `HashSet` here for best lookup performance. Please, note that `Set` won't allow for any duplicates though. Using a `Map` doesn't make much sense here since you're only interested in searching for the keys i.e. you don't have anything associated with it.

*Sample Code :*

```
Set<String> animals = new HashSet<String>(
                          Arrays.asList("cat", "dog", "squirrel", "raccoon"));
if (animals.contains("dog")) {
    System.out.println("Yep, dog's here!"); // prints
}
if (!animals.contains("aardvark")) {
    System.out.println("Ah, aardvark's missing!"); // prints
}
```

Note, that a `List` also has a `contains()` method but it iterates over all its elements to check if an item exists pretty much having the same poor performance you want to avoid when using the for loop.

Comment: Though I agree with your answer there are two points worth mentioning. 1. `HashSet` implementation uses `HashMap` internally. 2. Your referenced implementation essentially also uses a for-loop internally. As you see, they are to some extent contradictory with your answer.

Comment: "Your referenced implementation essentially also uses a for-loop internally." Uh, what? What are you talking about?

Comment: @skuntsel 1. Yes, that's correct but I didn't think it would have helped OP since he was considering using a `Map` directly. 2. The for-loop implementation of a `HashSet/Map` is entirely different (the use of hash codes giving near `O(1)` look-up performance) than that of a `List` that is more akin to what OP was doing: a for loop iterating over the elements.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I know it. That's why I told I agreed with your answer but found explanation kind of blurry :)

Comment: @nachokk Sorry, I could not respond to you because honestly I have no experience with using a *Trie* and so I don't know which one's better. But, as far as collisions go, you're correct: a *HashSet*'s performance basically comes down to how efficient the `hashCode()` implementation of its elements is. But, since OP is using `String` I think the performance should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a  [Trie data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Here is an implementation in [guava trie](https://code.google.com/p/google-collections/issues/detail?id=5) . And a trie complexity to search is `O(L) where L = stringToSearch.length();`

Comment: Could you estimate average search and insert complexity of both to justify that trie is 'much more performant' than a hash set?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Set` instead of a `Map` (or, in case of a `Map`, just use any value for the key):

```
if (mySet.contains(element)) {
    return element;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return myList.contains(searchTerm) ? searchTerm : null;
```

Comment: Note that he's asking for the best data structure, not how to make his code more terse.

Comment: "Is there a more efficient way to do this search?" yes there is one: List#contains

Comment: This is not more efficient - it does exactly the same thing as the OP's `for`-loop internally.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in `HashSet` as it uses hashing which is a technique for fast retrieval of elements as it uses hashcode to store them.

```
Sub obj = new Sub();
obj.items.add("one");
obj.items.add("two");
obj.items.add("three");

System.out.println(obj.items.contains("one"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to return you search term, you can do it like this

```
String result = myList.contains(searchTerm) ? result : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String[] arr = new String[]{"cat", "dog", "squirrel", "raccoon", "aardvark"};
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
    System.out.println(list.contains("dog") ? "found" : "not found");
```